# populate imageview with item selected from spinner

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-spinner

I want to be able to populate the imageview when an item is selected from the spinner! i have tried to implement onitemselectedlistener but could not get the code to work correctly so looking for help!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Context context = this;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<ItemData> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ItemData("Blue", R.drawable.blue));
    list.add(new ItemData("Green", R.drawable.green));
    list.add(new ItemData("Orange", R.drawable.orange));
    list.add(new ItemData("Pink", R.drawable.pink));
    list.add(new ItemData("Yellow", R.drawable.yel));

    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this,
            R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, list);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);


    ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainimage);


    myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
                }
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainimage);
            Animation a = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f);
            a.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            a.setRepeatCount(-1);
            a.setDuration(500);
            a.setFillAfter(true);
            a.setRepeatCount(7);
            myView.startAnimation(a);

        }
    });
}
```

}

```
public class ItemData {

String text;
Integer imageId;
public ItemData(String text, Integer imageId){
    this.text=text;
    this.imageId=imageId;
}

public String getText(){
    return text;
}

public Integer getImageId(){
    return imageId;
}
```

}

Comment: you referenced `R.id.mainimage` twice

Comment: yea i noticed i referenced it in the onClick method!

Comment: but, did you removed it? .the onClick already gives you `View` which is your imageview itself..try removing the second declaration and using `view.startAnimation(a);` instead

Comment: yes, the code runs fine! the method with the animation is not the concern! i am wanting to select an item from the spinner and have this item show in the imageview! there are 5 items in the list that the spinner shows

Comment: show the color when clicked on that item?

Comment: Yes thats correct, so it shows that colot drawable in the imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the color when you clicked on an item..

```
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ItemData data = sp.getSelectedItem();
            int res = data.getImageId();  //change Integer type to int  if error exists
            myView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(res));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: ok, but there are 5 items in the list to chose from and would need to return one of them depending on the one selected! also the ItemData is throwing an error, incompatible types

Comment: can you share your itemData class also

Comment: just added the itemdata class

Comment: the 2 errors that show now are on the sp and the myView, the error says there accessed from inner class and need to be declared final!

Comment: figured it, i changed to...ItemData data = (ItemData) sp.getSelectedItem(); it now works

Comment: i had to cast it

Comment: much appreciated i am greatful for your help thank you

Comment: in regards to the animation, is there a way i could speed it up? make the animation faster?

Comment: try adding`hardwareAccelerated="true"` inside `<activity>`  in the androidmanifest file